# Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE в php Curl

Tags: php, curl, долгий-запрос

Использую cUrl в PHP для получения довольно большого файла (> 1Гб). До вчерашнего дня все работало стабильно. Но сегодня начал получать ошибку:

> transfer closed with 8412120 bytes remaining to read

Почитав инфу, подключил в настройки cUrl CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE и CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE. Вот код cUrl-запроса

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://***/file/get');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$output   = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$info     = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r(curl_error($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Но теперь ответ от cUrl содержит ошибку:
undefined constant CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE - assumed 'CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE'. Тоже самое с CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE.

И вроде бы понятно, что таких надстроек нет в данной версии libcurl (и/или php). 
Но я использую PHP 7.2.2 и cUrl 7.67.0

Comment: попробуйте сами объявить тогда `define('CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE', 213)`, коли она не документирована в пхп. 214 для idle - https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curl.h

Comment: Любопытно, но спустя пару часов предупреждение исчезло и запрос начал корректно отрабатываться. Что это - кеширование конфигурации php? Сервер был перезагружен до этого пару раз и изменений не было.